# ERROR ITMS-90259: "Bad Bundle Executable. You must include a valid CFBundleExecutable key in your bundle's information property list file

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm working on a multi-platform iOS and Mac app. When I try and Archive and Distribute to the App Store I run into this issue:

ERROR ITMS-90259: "Bad Bundle Executable. You must include a valid CFBundleExecutable key in your bundle's information property list file."

- Verified that the Info.plist for the Mac target has a CFBundleExecutable
- Tried Xcode 12 & 13
- Tried using App Transporter
- Used Xcode 13 RC and let that auto-generate the Info.plist
  I've tried everything I could find online - there's not much - and I can't get the upload to succeed.

However, I was able to replicate the issue with an entirely empty project. No dependencies, no code, nothing. The project archives successfully, but the upload fails.

Any help would be appreciated. I've spent two days on this already.

An example project that fails: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qUN5lHEWNyNHQV54fYPXMeRsuO-cpHqW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What's the value of `CFBundleExecutable` in your `Info.plist`?

Comment: $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

Comment: I tried putting the executable's name directly. But, I think the fact that an empty project fails to upload is a sign that something else is wrong. Any ideas where I should look next? The only options I see are the fact that my project includes Entitlements and that I'm using Xcode 13 RC instead of a "non-beta" release.

Comment: @BenAffleck Appreciate you helping out! I've spent 2 days on this and I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: Hmmmm my assumption was that maybe `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)` contains some characters that AppStore doesn't like. Try submitting your app with Transporter by Apple: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

We had two issues causing this, making it fail when uploading a Mac build to iTunes. The first issue, we had included a package (from Steam), that had its own plist and post build script.
com.rlabrecque.steamworks.net/Editor/RedistCopy.cs - build script
com.rlabrecque.steamworks.net/Plugins/steam_api.bundle.meta - folder with plugin and plist

We renamed the post build script and removed the plugin folder, not 100% sure if the renaming was needed.

Then, we had this in our own post build script that was causing issues, so we removed it too.
`rootDict.SetString("CFBundleExecutable", "${EXECUTABLE_NAME}");`

Then it worked! Also worth noting that we believe the CFBundleExecutable didnt actually end up matching the file name e.g. the file produced was a.pkg and the plist says:

```
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>b</string>
```

But seems iTunes was ok with that. We use Unity and it seems in the pList the string was set to the "Product Name" (Edit > Project Settings > Player, at the top, "Product Name").

We also didnt need to use Transporter to upload.